# Is /etc/sudoers file only suppose to have read only permissions?

Tags: permissions, sudo

```
-r--r-----   1 root root     723 Jan 31  2012 sudoers
```

My dist-update frequently fails.
At boot my system frequently asks for file system check. (My system-hardware is file)

I am using

> vksTP 3.5.0-25-generic #39~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Feb 26 00:07:14 UTC
>   2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

From root prompt, is it safe for me to do (I donot know if that will work, as the file is read only)

```
chmod g+w /etc/sudors
```

my user is added in root group

```
vks@vksTP:~$ sudo adduser vks root
The user `vks' is already a member of `root'.
```

Please suggest, I may have superficial knowledge on perms, and I may be confusing things up. Please let me know if there is any other important piece of information I am missing ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, `/etc/sudoers` is supposed to have those permissions, being read-only for user and group, nothing else. The reason being that you aren't supposed to edit the sudoers file directly, but by using the `visudo` wrapper, which provides some sanity checking before writing a new sudoers file.

You can control what editor visudo uses by setting the VISUAL alt. EDITOR environment variable.

```
$ sudo EDITOR=emacs visudo
```

Comment: Thanks. I was able to add the following, but i dont know if this is the right thing to do... # User privilege specification
root ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
vks ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL